# Pass Array of Points as parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, point

I have an array of points, which is defined as following:

```
const int pNum = 8;
Point framePt[pNum];
```

And I want to pass it to a function which will access the values in the array and get the size of the array as well. So I define the function like below:

```
void getFrameCord(Point *framePt)
```

But this does not pass the array indeed. So could anyone help me with this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have to tell the function about the number of elements in the array somehow. A pointer to an element only indicates where that particular element is, it does not carry any information such as whether that element is part of an array (let alone how big that array is).

Some possible solutions:

---

```
void getFrameCord(Point *framePt, size_t num_points);
// ...
getFrameCord(framePt, pNum);
```

---

```
template<size_t N>
void getFrameCord(Point (&framePt)[N])
{ /* ... */ }

// ...
getFrameCord(framePt);
```

---

```
template<typename InputIterator>
void getFrameCord(InputIterator b, InputIterator e)
{
    // ...
}

// ...
getFrameCord( std::begin(framePt), std::end(framePt) )
```

The last one of these will let you use `getFrameCord` with any container of points or any part of a container; it doesn't constrain the caller to store points in a contiguous array.

Comment: I would add a note about pointers in general; I'm guessing the OP comes from a high level language where arrays are actually complex Objects that carry some meta-data about how big the array is. In c/c++ this is not the case, an array pointer is very basic, it's simply an arrow that says <thing starts here>, if you want your function to have meta-data about how big that thing is then you need to pass that separately, or use a more complex data-type like the examples @MattMcNabb suggests.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth OK, improved my wording. Using `std::array` instead of a C-style array is an improvement in general, however I didn't suggest making `getFrameCord` accept one because that makes the function even less general.

Comment: You might consider adding an example usage of `getFrameCord(InputIterator, InputIterator)` with a standard container such as `std::vector`.